# I am Always getting the Instance of Parent Class.But i need a child one

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I Want to get a instance of child class but i am getting always parent class instance can anybody explain me why?? According to the XMLType ID i am getting the instace of children(string or anyURI) etc.but in some conditions i need child class instance.

code::

```
public abstract class WSType 

    public final static WSType getInstance(int xmlTypeId) {
        switch (xmlTypeId) {
        case STRING: return WSStringType2.getInstance(); //**here i am always getting Parent class but  i am calling instance of WSStringType2.**
        case ANYURI: return WSAnyURIType2.getInstance();
        }
    }

    public final static WSType getInstance(int xmlTypeId, String data) throws XCallException {
        WSType wsData = WSType.getInstance(xmlTypeId); /**/calling happening Here**

  }

    }
public class WSStringType extends WSType {

    protected String m_data;


    public WSStringType() { m_data = "'"; }
    public WSStringType(String name){ m_data=name; }

    public static WSStringType getInstance() {
        return new WSStringType();
    }


}
class WSStringType2 extends WSStringType {

   public WSStringType2() { m_data = "'"; }
   public static WSStringType2 getInstance() {
        return new WSStringType2();
    }

   public WSStringType2(String newValue){
         super(newValue);
   }


}
```

Comment: did you tried to cast to chield before getting instance?

Comment: this would be a better question if the code sample actually could run and produce some result, instead of being a blob of code where it's hard to tell what you're calling and what you expect. (where better = 'more likely to get you a relevant answer')

Comment: if i cast i am generating only one class objects right every time..but they will be changing depending on what operation i wana do..

Answer (score 2):

The return type of the `getInstance(int xmlTypeId)` is `WSType` which is the parent. You can simply cast it to `WSStringType2` because `WSStringType2` extends `WSStringType` and `WSStringType` extends `WSType`

```
WSType wt = WSType.getInstance(STRING);
WSStringType2 wt2 = null;
if (t instanceof WSStringType2) {
    wt2 = (WSStringType2) wt;
}
```